# How do you reset your password for thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, email, password-recovery

I am trying to set up a Thunderbird account, but it keeps telling me that my password is wrong. When I went to Edit/Preferences/Security/Passwords, I discovered my suspicions were correct. But I think I may be experiencing a problem that may be altogether different. When I put in my correct username and password, this is what comes up.

[image]

I just don't know what this means or what it was that I did wrong. Thunderbird opens up, I just always get this error message.

Comment: Hi BJsgoodlife, I posted my answer based on the title of your question, are you sure that that is the problem? (in other words that you are using the right password?)

Comment: Make sure that you have typed correctly BOTH username (i.e. email address) and password. It in not uncommon to miss-type the mail address.

Comment: edited my answer to check what could be wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove existing passwords, go to edit > preferences, click on the security icon. Then the "passwords" tab, the "saved passwords" button, in the next window: "show passwords"

In the list of accounts and passwords, select your password and choose "remove" (down left)

However, something else seems to be wrong. If the password is incorrect, you were probably offered to enter a new password. If the password is rejected again and you are sure it is correct, you should check the server settings.

Settings should be like this:

[image]

Also check if IMAP is enabled in your Gmail account (on the Gmail webmail website), although that is unlikely to be the problem.

See also [this reference](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-gmail)

Answer (score 0):

Sign into your Gmail account with the password you believe is correct to test it. Also make sure that your Caps Lock is not on because the password is case sensitive.  If you are successful then you can try it again in Thunderbird.